# Russian and German support in Google's TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to create an app which would use Google's TTS to read English, German and Russian texts. However currently it only speaks English. The device runs on Android 4.2.1 with Google TTS 3.10.9.

Below is the code I use for testing.

```
        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
//                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.GERMANY);
//                    t1.setLanguage(new Locale("ru"));
                    Log.d("TTS", "ok");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TTS", "error");
                }
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t1.speak("What is your name?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
//                t1.speak("Wie heisst du?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
//                t1.speak("Как Вас зовут?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            }
        });
```

When I run the same code on an emulator on Android 7 I can hear all the three languages being spoken.

I couldn't find any information which would help me to answer the question: Since which version does TTS support German and Russian? The wiki page only says that the support for Russian was added in 2014. The corresponding Google Play page doesn't have any information related to versions.
When I open the TTS page on Google Play with that device I only see "Installed" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to turn on Wi-Fi on the device and add German and Russian in "Settings -> Language & Input -> Google voice typing -> Voices". After that the languages were downloaded and the app worked as desired.